# How to convert a column header and its value into row in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns say `col1, col2, col3`. The table has many rows in it.

Let's assume `val1, val2, val3` is one such row. I want to get the result as

```
Col1, Val1
Col2, Val2
Col3, Val3
```

That is 3 rows - one for each column and its value.

I am using SQL Server 2008. I read about pivots. Are pivots a way to solve this problem? Can someone route me to some examples or solutions how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (1,1,1)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.Col1,
        t.Col2,
        t.Col3
    FROM
        @T AS t
) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR Col IN
    (Col1,Col2,Col3)
) AS unpvt
```

**Output**

```
1   Col1
1   Col2
1   Col3
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Arion. This is what i was looking exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To do this kind of thing read the following: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Pivot function allow you to convert row values in from of column..

Also check : [Dynamic Pivoting in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27776/Dynamic-Pivoting-in-SQL-Server)

Example :

```
create table #temptable(colorname varchar(25),Hexa varchar(7),rgb varchar(1), rgbvalue tinyint)    
GO   
insert into #temptable values('Violet','#8B00FF','r',139);   
insert into #temptable values('Violet','#8B00FF','g',0);   
insert into #temptable values('Violet','#8B00FF','b',255);   
insert into #temptable values('Indigo','#4B0082','r',75);   
insert into #temptable values('Indigo','#4B0082','g',0);   
insert into #temptable values('Indigo','#4B0082','b',130);   
insert into #temptable values('Blue','#0000FF','r',0);   
insert into #temptable values('Blue','#0000FF','g',0);   
insert into #temptable values('Blue','#0000FF','b',255);



SELECT colorname,hexa,[r], [g], [b]   
FROM  
(SELECT colorname,hexa,rgb,rgbvalue   
    FROM #temptable) AS TableToBePivoted   
PIVOT   
(   
sum(rgbvalue)   
FOR rgb IN ([r], [g], [b])   
) AS PivotedTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temproary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #table2
(
name NCHAR,
bonus INT
)
```

Now Select and execute the below statement if there is an empty.

```
SELECT * FROM #table2

INSERT INTO #table2 (name,bonus) VALUES ('A',10)
INSERT INTO #table2 (name,bonus) VALUES ('B',20)
INSERT INTO #table2 (name,bonus) VALUES ('C',30)
```

After insert the values into table. select and execute the below line if you get records:

```
SELECT * FROM #table2
```

Input:

```
name    bonus
A   10
B   20
C   30
```

Change the input into like this result

Result:

```
Cost        A    B  C
Bonus   10  20  30
```

By using this code:

```
SELECT 'Bonus' AS Cost, 
[A],[B],[C]
FROM
(SELECT name, Bonus 
FROM #table2) AS TempTbl 
PIVOT
(
    AVG(bonus)
    FOR [name] IN ([A],[B],[C])
) AS PivotTable;
```