# SQL Server map rows with columns of different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create a result based on row and column value mapping. This is an example

First table (#column_table) has colunm_id and column_name.

[image]

Second table #column_value has values for the rows in First Table.

[image]

I want to create a dataset that looks like below:

[image]

How do I achieve that?

Here are the temp tables for data setup.

```
create table #column_table (column_id int, column_name varchar(50) )

insert into #column_table
values
(1, 'FirstName'),
(2, 'LastName'),
(3, 'Address'),
(4, 'Phone')


create table #column_value(FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Phone varchar(50),)

insert into #column_value
values
('John','Smith','1234567')

select * from  #column_table
select * from #column_value
```

Comment: Is there only 1 row in `#column_value`?

Comment: yeah. #column_value will have only one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UNPIVOT** would be more performant, but if you need a more dynamic approach without actually using Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select  D.Column_ID
       ,Column_Value = C.Value
 From  #column_value A
 Cross Apply (values (convert(xml,(Select A.* For XML Raw)))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) C
 Join #column_table D on C.Item=D.Column_Name
```

**Returns**

```
Column_ID   Column_Value
1           John
2           Smith
4           1234567
```

Comment: Thanks John. Result is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using **UnPivot** which is more performant, but as @JohnCappelleti mentioned you need to implement a **Dynamic SQL** logic:

*Side Notes: i used `like '#column_value%'` not `= '#column_value'` because the example is handling a temp table. Also, You should replace `#column_value` and `#column_table` by corresponding tables names. Also, i used `tempdb.information_schema` because temp tables are stored in `tempdb` database.*

```
--Create Tables and insert values
create table #column_table (column_id int, column_name varchar(50) )

insert into #column_table
values
(1, 'FirstName'),
(2, 'LastName'),
(3, 'Address'),
(4, 'Phone')


create table #column_value(FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Phone varchar(50),)

insert into #column_value
values
('John','Smith','1234567')

select * from  #column_table
select * from #column_value

--Get columns found in both tables
SELECT t2.column_id,t2.column_name 
INTO #tblTemp
from tempdb.information_schema.columns t1
inner join #column_table t2 on t1.COLUMN_NAME = t2.column_name
where t1.table_name like '#column_value%'

--Building Dynamic Query
DECLARE @strQuery VARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT '
DECLARE @strUnPivot as varchar(max) = ' UNPIVOT ([Value] for [Column_ID] IN ('
SELECT @strUnPivot = ISNULL(@strUnPivot,'') + '[' + CAST(column_id as varchar(10)) + '] ,' From  #tblTemp
SELECT  @strQuery = @strQuery + '[' + column_name + '] AS "' + CAST(column_id as varchar(10)) + '",' From  #tblTemp

SELECT @strQuery = SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM #column_value)  AS p ' + SUBSTRING(@strUnPivot,1,LEN(@strUnPivot) - 1) + ')) AS unpvt '

--Execute Query
EXEC(@strQuery)
```

**Result**

[image]

**References**

- [How to convert a column header and its value into row in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944910/how-to-convert-a-column-header-and-its-value-into-row-in-sql)
- [Select non-empty columns using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895126/select-non-empty-columns-using-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks. This looks great.

Answer (score 1):

With `CASE` and a cross join:

```
select 
  ct.column_id,
  case ct.column_id
    when 1 then cv.FirstName
    when 2 then cv.LastName
    when 4 then cv.Phone
  end column_value
from #column_table ct cross join #column_value cv
where ct.column_id <> 3
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4be0ecfe3eaff0a3bdcd7f6273028624)